# how can i found out from where an implicit value is being picked

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

I am observing a strange behavior. In on of my test cases, I am using `contentAsJson`. In that test case, the compiler is not complaining that I have to provide an `implicit` value for `Timeout` and `Materializer`

```
class UserControllerUnitSpec extends PlaySpec with BeforeAndAfterAll with BeforeAndAfterEach with OneAppPerSuiteWithComponents{
..
  "User signup request with body but with incorrect profile data " should {
    "return error message " in {

...val resultFuture: Future[Result] = testEnv.controller.signupUser(request)
    val responseBodyAsJsValue: JsValue = contentAsJson(resultFuture)//works
...
}
}
```

But in another test case, the compiler gives error that I need to provide the value

```
class QuestionsControllerUnitSpec extends PlaySpec with BeforeAndAfterAll with BeforeAndAfterEach with OneAppPerSuiteWithComponents{
...
"newQuestion" should {
    "should return error if the size of the body in the request is more than the maximum allowed size" in {
...
val response:Accumulator[ByteString,Result] = questionController.newQuestion(request)
val responseBody = contentAsJson(response)//(Timeout(Duration(5000,"millis")),testEnv.testEnv.mat). 
...
}
```

I get error

```
Error:(1485, 39) could not find implicit value for parameter mat: akka.stream.Materializer
      val responseBody = contentAsJson(response)//(Timeout(Duration(5000,"millis")),testEnv.testEnv.mat)
```

How can I debug why one is working but the other isn't?

UPDATE - added return types after Mario's answer.

Comment: at least have the courtesy to tell why the question was marked down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try providing implicit `Materializer` like so

```
import play.api.test.Helpers._
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
val responseBody = contentAsJson(response)
```

instead of explicit `testEnv.testEnv.mat`

```
contentAsJson(response)(Timeout(Duration(5000,"millis")),testEnv.testEnv.mat)
```

Regarding the difference between the two tests, note there are two overloaded versions of `contentAsJson`

```
def contentAsJson(of: Future[Result])(implicit timeout: Timeout, mat: Materializer = NoMaterializer): JsValue

def contentAsJson(of: Accumulator[ByteString, Result])(implicit timeout: Timeout, mat: Materializer): JsValue
```

where in the first case we see default `Materializer` argument is provided

```
mat: Materializer = NoMaterializer
```

while in the second case we have to provided our own. Therefore it is likely that in the first test the type of `resultFuture` is `Future[Result]` whilst in the second test the return type of `response` is `Accumulator`.

Regarding finding out where the implicit is provided from, personally I use IntelliJ's `View | Show Implicit Hints` feature.

Comment: You were bang on about the return types. The `signupUser` is `Action` of type `Action[AnyContent]` and `newQuestion` is `Action` of type `Action[Either[MaxSizeExceeded,AnyContent]`. But why does calling one returns `Future[Result]` while calling the other returns `Accumulator[ByteString,Result]`

Comment: Also, if you look at this question I opened earlier, shouldn't I get `Getting .UnsupportedOperationException: NoMaterializer does not provide an ExecutionContext Error` error for when `NoMaterializer` is used a default value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577155/getting-unsupportedoperationexception-nomaterializer-does-not-provide-an-execu

Comment: `Action[Either[MaxSizeExceeded,AnyContent]` indicates to me that you are using a custom parser. Could you edit the question with the relevant controller snippets?

Comment: to keep topics separate, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581602/request-body-is-showing-as-anycontentasraw-with-inmemory-0

Comment: In summary, I want to limit the size of incoming request. The code works in dev environment but I am struggling to create a unit test for it.

Comment: I understood why NoMaterializer exception is not thrown for Future[Result]. It's because the Materializer is not used there - `def contentAsJson(of: Future[Result])(implicit timeout: Timeout, mat: Materializer = NoMaterializer): JsValue = Json.parse(contentAsString(of))`. But the Accumulator version uses the materialiser `def contentAsJson(of: Accumulator[ByteString, Result])(implicit timeout: Timeout, mat: Materializer): JsValue = contentAsJson(of.run())`