# Testing Play framework controller that streams responses

Tags: scala, playframework, stream

I have a controller that sends a chunked response:

```
def streamDatase2t(query:String): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    req =>
        serivce.getIterator(query).map(res => {
            Ok.chunked(Source.apply(res))
        })
  }
```

When I try to inspect the returned content in the controller spec I get an exception:

```
  "return 200 response with the content of the iterator" in {
      when(serivce.getIterator
      (Matchers.any[Request.DatasetLoad],
        Matchers.any[ResponseFormat], Matchers.any[Int]))
        .thenReturn(Future.successful(new FakeIterable(List("One", "Two", "Three").iterator)))

      val fakeRequest = FakeRequest.apply("GET", s"/data")

      val result = Helpers.route(fakeApp, fakeRequest).get
      checkStatus(result, OK)
      contentAsString(result) // <-- exception here ! 
    }
```

Exception:

```
NoMaterializer cannot materialize
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: NoMaterializer cannot materialize
    at play.api.test.NoMaterializer$.materialize(Helpers.scala:732)
    at akka.stream.scaladsl.RunnableGraph.run(Flow.scala:629)
    at akka.stream.scaladsl.Source.runWith(Source.scala:106)
    at akka.stream.scaladsl.Source.runFold(Source.scala:117)
    at play.api.http.HttpEntity.consumeData(HttpEntity.scala:49)
    at play.api.http.HttpEntity.consumeData$(HttpEntity.scala:48)
    at play.api.http.HttpEntity$Chunked.consumeData(HttpEntity.scala:117)
    at play.api.test.ResultExtractors.contentAsBytes(Helpers.scala:381)
    at play.api.test.ResultExtractors.contentAsBytes$(Helpers.scala:379)
    at play.api.test.Helpers$.contentAsBytes(Helpers.scala:676)
```

Comment: Consider removing tags from the title as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: @MarioGalic This is kinda strange actually, but in Google Search engine people tend to click on the titles that mostly has keywords that they use. Would be a problem to keep it as is ?

Answer (score 3):

As the Exception states `NoMaterializer cannot materialize` you may need to add a `Materializer`:

```
implicit lazy val mat = ActorMaterializer()
implicit lazy val ec = instanceOf[ExecutionContext]
```

Answer (score 3):

[`contentAsString`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/701a8e4a527725ad137dcc7f69b5cef8ce1bb19c/testkit/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala#L363) has `NoMaterializer` as the default argument

```
def contentAsString(of: Future[Result])(implicit timeout: Timeout, mat: Materializer = NoMaterializer): String
```

[`NoMaterializer`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/ddf3a7ee4285212ec665826ec268ef32b5a76000/testkit/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/NoMaterializer.scala#L22) just throws `UnsupportedOperationException` for everything so try providing [your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57589738/5205022)

```
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
```

[play-scala-streaming-example](https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.8.x/play-scala-streaming-example) demonstrates how we might write a test for streaming controller.

---

Addressing the comment, consider the following two routes which illustrate the difference between a **strict** and non-strict (chunked, streamed) body

```
def nonStrictBody = Action {
  val source = Source.apply(List("woo", "h", "oo"))
  Ok.chunked(source)
}

def strictBody = Action {
  Ok("woohoo")
}
```

When calling `contentAsString` on a strict body, then materializer will not be used, hence `NoMaterializer` is [sufficient](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/test/NoMaterializer$.html)

> In 99% of cases, when running tests against the result body, you don't
>   actually need a materializer since it's a **strict** body. So, rather than
>   always requiring an implicit materializer, we use one if provided,
>   otherwise we have a default one that simply throws an exception if
>   used.

However when calling `contentAsString` on a [chunked](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/http/HttpEntity$$Chunked.html) or [streamed](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/http/HttpEntity$$Streamed.html) body, as it is the case in the `nonStrictBody` route, then we need to provide a proper `Materializer`.

Comment: But why when I change the service to return a string instead of Iterator[String] it doesn't require materializer ?